# EOF -1 vs an internal -1 data

Tags: java, io, eof

How is the -1 returned by **InputStream** methods when reaching the end of the stream distinguished from a -1 in the stream data?

Comment: Data can't contain "-1". Every byte is returned as 0-255. (It's unfortunate that bytes are signed in Java... it's very rarely useful to view them that way.) From the docs for InputStream.read: "The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned". If that isn't clear to you, please edit your question to clarify what difficulty you're having.

Comment: So if i tried to write a -1 to a file and someone else tried to read it will get 255 and won't have no idea that i tried to (carelessly) write -1 because it is not intended to work that way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "write -1 to a file"?  At base, a file is made of bytes.  Do you mean a single byte with all one bits?  Then that is read as a single byte with all one bits - as an integer result, that will be returned as 255.  If you mean four bytes each with all one bits, then you will see four bytes, which you can assemble into a single four-byte int if you wish.  To restate: files are made of bytes, and it follows that if you want to write entities that are larger than a byte, readers must be in agreement with how to interpret the bytes to recover the 'sense' of what was written.

Comment: @access yes I mean the first statement thanks